# How can an App crash the device almost completely?

Tags: java, android

I have a fairly complex android app here, which seems to be able to crash exactly one android device: the gigaset maxwell 10 (S, too). The strange thing on this is: the complete device UI freeze, so even the android toolbar cannot be brought back via a swipe from the top. Once within this state it wont recover even after days. It is not only the touch of the screen, sometimes my UI freezes, sometimes it still continues to show videos. Sometimes I can connect via adb, sometimes not. But when I do, I cant interact via adb-touches with my (running?) app.

I got the log from the latest crash - although I dont know if anyone wants to read it or can help me with it. You find it below.

I have absolutely no idea, how an android app can crash a device like mine do. I thought the OS should kill the application if anything goes wrong, and protect itself from getting harmed. Maybe someone has seen anything similar and can direct my research to the right.

The app in question touches videoplayback, sip communication, lots of network communications, has multiple services running in the background, and takes firebase messages. It runs in fullscreen with a wakelock.

```
[I shortened some logs]
05-14 15:11:25.639 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:25.642 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:25.643 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:25.938 I/art     ( 8834): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22039(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 239(5MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 4.176ms total 203.600ms
05-14 15:11:26.306 W/AudioFlinger(  196): RecordThread: buffer overflow
05-14 15:11:26.764 I/AudioFlinger(  196): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4101) from active list on thread 0xb54d4000
05-14 15:11:28.298 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
[Deleted 7 of those messages]
05-14 15:11:31.261 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:31.265 W/audio_hw_primary(  196): do_output_standby... 0, device 2
05-14 15:11:31.265 I/audio_hw_primary(  196): get_dvf_device_to_close() device_to_close 2, prev dev 2, new device 0
05-14 15:11:31.265 V/audio_hw_primary(  196): get_dvf_device_to_close() prev/new dev is 0 (or both 0), set device 2
05-14 15:11:31.265 W/audio_hw_primary(  196): get_dvf_device_to_close() device to close 2
05-14 15:11:31.265 E/audio_hw_primary(  196): do_out_standby: Disable device 0x2
05-14 15:11:31.265 E/CMBS CLIENT WRAPPER(  196): The value of  binder->pingBinder is [0]
05-14 15:11:31.265 V/CMBS CLIENT(  196): set audio event=2 :: response=0
05-14 15:11:31.265 W/audio_hw_primary(  196): do_out_standby: prev_device 0x0
05-14 15:11:31.265 V/CMBS_SERVER(  198): BnCMBSServer::onTransact(6) 17
05-14 15:11:31.266 D/CMBS_SERVER(  198): Event got 6
05-14 15:11:31.266 V/CMBS    (  198): audioRoutingViaCMBS: deviceID = 2 bWideBand = 1 state 0
05-14 15:11:31.266 I/CMBS    (  198): audioRoutingViaCMBS: output device
05-14 15:11:31.266 V/CMBS    (  198): deviceAudioRoutingViaCMBS: deviceID = 2 bWideBand = 1 state 0, deviceType 1
05-14 15:11:31.266 E/CMBS    (  198): deviceAudioRoutingViaCMBS: disable deviceIdx 0 & type 1
05-14 15:11:31.266 V/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice: device idx = 0, dev type 1, i/p dev 0, o/p dev 1 & count 1
05-14 15:11:31.266 I/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice: disable Device 0 channel ID =240
05-14 15:11:31.266 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 257
05-14 15:11:31.266 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 257
05-14 15:11:31.287 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.287 V/CMBS    (  198): cmbsevent_Interrupt_Event_responses entry
05-14 15:11:31.287 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 257 n_InfoLen = 0 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.287 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 257 LinuxContainer = 257 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.287 V/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice: disable end point for deviceIdx 0 and channel 0
05-14 15:11:31.287 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 241
05-14 15:11:31.287 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 241
05-14 15:11:31.307 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.307 V/CMBS    (  198): cmbsevent_Interrupt_Event_responses entry
05-14 15:11:31.307 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 241 n_InfoLen = 0 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.307 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 241 LinuxContainer = 241 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.307 V/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice: disable end point for deviceIdx 0 and channel 1
05-14 15:11:31.307 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 241
05-14 15:11:31.308 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 241
05-14 15:11:31.327 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.327 V/CMBS    (  198): cmbsevent_Interrupt_Event_responses entry
05-14 15:11:31.328 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 241 n_InfoLen = 0 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.328 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 241 LinuxContainer = 241 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.328 V/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice(0): close channel ID f0
05-14 15:11:31.328 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 66
05-14 15:11:31.328 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 66
05-14 15:11:31.349 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.350 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 66 n_InfoLen = 4 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.350 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 66 LinuxContainer = 66 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.350 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 250
05-14 15:11:31.350 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 250
05-14 15:11:31.371 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.371 V/CMBS    (  198): cmbsevent_Interrupt_Event_responses entry
05-14 15:11:31.371 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 250 n_InfoLen = 0 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.372 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 250 LinuxContainer = 250 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.372 E/CMBS    (  198): deviceAudioRoutingViaCMBS: Disable Tweeter
05-14 15:11:31.372 V/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice: device idx = 1, dev type 1, i/p dev 0, o/p dev 1 & count 1
05-14 15:11:31.372 I/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice: disable Device 1 channel ID =242
05-14 15:11:31.372 V/CMBS    (  198): disableDevice(1): close channel ID f2
05-14 15:11:31.372 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 66
05-14 15:11:31.372 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 66
05-14 15:11:31.394 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.394 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 66 n_InfoLen = 4 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.394 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 66 LinuxContainer = 66 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.394 E/CMBS    (  198): Message response event = 250
05-14 15:11:31.395 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer waiting for event n_Event = 250
05-14 15:11:31.418 E/        (  198): CB Thread: Sync word detected, reset DataIndex
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS    (  198): cmbsevent_Interrupt_Event_responses entry
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS    (  198): Event recieved from target event = 250 n_InfoLen = 0 sizeof(ST_CFR_IE_LIST) = 12
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS    (  198): appcmbs_WaitForContainer after dequeue end  n_Event = 250 LinuxContainer = 250 nRetVal = 0
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS    (  198): deviceAudioRoutingViaCMBS: Disable device result 1
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS    (  198): Endpoint access count for device 2 is 1
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS    (  198): logEndpointAccessCount: Total device count is 1
05-14 15:11:31.419 E/CMBS    (  198): deviceAudioRoutingViaCMBS(0): inDev 0, outDev 0
05-14 15:11:31.419 E/CMBS    (  198): adudioRoutingViaCMBS: deviceID 0 end with result 1
05-14 15:11:31.419 I/CMBS    (  198): audioRoutingViaCMBS deviceID 0x0 ret 1 OUT
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS_SERVER(  198): return of audio_event[Device ID = 2, bWideBand = 1, State = 0] is 1
05-14 15:11:31.419 V/CMBS_SERVER(  198):  The event [6] has been completed with return[1], Now will delete it
05-14 15:11:33.961 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
[Deleted 6 of those messages]
05-14 15:11:36.777 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:37.068 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 5001.4ms since event, 5001.0ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 7964.0ms.
05-14 15:11:37.088 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 7964.0ms.
05-14 15:11:37.130 I/Process (  510): Sending signal. PID: 8834 SIG: 3
05-14 15:11:37.131 I/art     ( 8834): Thread[5,tid=8843,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4432800,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
05-14 15:11:37.331 I/Process (  510): Sending signal. PID: 510 SIG: 3
05-14 15:11:37.331 I/art     (  510): Thread[5,tid=519,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4428c00,peer=0x12c020a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
05-14 15:11:38.743 I/Process (  510): Sending signal. PID: 1413 SIG: 3
05-14 15:11:38.744 I/art     ( 1413): Thread[5,tid=1422,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4432800,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
05-14 15:11:38.778 I/Process (  510): Sending signal. PID: 1431 SIG: 3
05-14 15:11:38.778 I/art     (  510): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-14 15:11:38.778 I/art     ( 1431): Thread[5,tid=1440,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4432800,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
05-14 15:11:38.899 I/art     ( 1431): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-14 15:11:38.899 I/Process (  510): Sending signal. PID: 1136 SIG: 3
05-14 15:11:38.899 I/art     ( 1136): Thread[5,tid=1147,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4432800,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
05-14 15:11:39.110 I/art     ( 1413): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-14 15:11:39.247 I/art     ( 1136): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-14 15:11:39.511 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:39.695 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:42.136 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 6965.0ms since event, 5005.4ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 13031.9ms.
05-14 15:11:42.162 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 13031.9ms.
05-14 15:11:42.590 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:42.650 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): 15:11:45.186   pjsua_core.c  .RX 629 bytes Request msg BYE/cseq=102 (rdata0x91d8a1e0) from TLS 192.168.199.1:5061:
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): BYE sip:64@192.168.199.120:32983;transport=TLS;ob SIP/2.0
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.199.1:5061;branch=z9hG4bK3417ebf5;rport
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): Max-Forwards: 70
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): From: sip:65@192.168.199.1;tag=as7d6a86b9
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): To: sip:64@192.168.199.1;tag=0e4ec4dc-8447-4755-a5dc-0241b4f07b08
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): Call-ID: 9b22ec82-e6ec-4fce-99ec-79536d75c23e
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): CSeq: 102 BYE
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 13.7.0~dfsg-0~ppa1
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="Maxwell 10_2", realm="asterisk", algorithm=MD5, uri="sips:192.168.199.1", nonce="18e14dce", response="c4515d0215d9348c2bc4b0755a3361c3"
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): Content-Length: 0
05-14 15:11:45.186 D/PJSUA Native( 8834): --end msg--
05-14 15:11:45.333 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:45.389 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:47.180 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 8729.7ms since event, 5005.1ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 18076.4ms.
05-14 15:11:47.200 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 18076.4ms.
05-14 15:11:48.104 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:48.161 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:50.894 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:50.957 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:11:51.800 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:11:51.805 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:11:53.679 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:10.448 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:12.879 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 5005.6ms since event, 5005.2ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 43775.0ms.
05-14 15:12:12.914 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 43775.0ms.
05-14 15:12:13.167 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:13.239 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:15.970 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:16.022 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:17.928 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 8946.6ms since event, 5004.4ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 48823.7ms.
05-14 15:12:17.978 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 48823.7ms.
05-14 15:12:18.768 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:18.827 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:21.528 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:21.589 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:21.802 I/Process (  510): Sending signal. PID: 510 SIG: 3
05-14 15:12:21.802 I/art     (  510): Thread[5,tid=519,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4428c00,peer=0x12c020a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
05-14 15:12:22.992 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:12:22.994 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:12:32.020 W/libbacktrace(  510): void ThreadEntry::Wait(int): pthread_cond_timedwait failed: Connection timed out
05-14 15:12:33.272 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
[Deleted 13 of those messages]
05-14 15:12:33.273 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:12:33.274 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:33.275 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
[Deleted 184 of those messages]
05-14 15:12:33.296 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:12:33.296 I/art     (  510): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-14 15:12:33.296 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
[Deleted 167 of those messages]
05-14 15:12:33.314 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:12:33.333 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:36.122 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:12:38.320 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
[Deleted 103 of those messages]
05-14 15:12:38.332 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:12:38.856 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
[Deleted 18 of those messages]
05-14 15:13:14.176 D/NtpTrustedTime(  510): currentTimeMillis() cache hit
05-14 15:18:07.040 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 5005.8ms since event, 5005.3ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 397936.0ms.
05-14 15:18:07.090 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 397936.0ms.
05-14 15:18:12.106 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Application is not responding: Window{118353f3 u0 my.stupid.MainActivity}.  It has been 9634.3ms since event, 5005.3ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 403001.8ms.
05-14 15:18:12.179 I/WindowManager(  510): Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.stupid.MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 7.  Wait queue head age: 403001.8ms.
05-14 15:18:17.194 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
[Deleted 595 of those messages]
05-14 15:18:22.263 I/InputDispatcher(  510): Dropped event because it is stale.
05-14 15:19:27.473 I/ValidateNoPeople(  510): skipping global notification
05-14 15:19:27.478 I/ValidateNoPeople(  510): skipping global notification
05-14 15:21:12.842 W/sh      ( 9990): type=1400 audit(0.0:15): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728768]" dev="sockfs" ino=728768 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:12.862 W/sh      ( 9990): type=1400 audit(0.0:16): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728768]" dev="sockfs" ino=728768 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:12.978 E/cutils-trace( 9992): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-14 15:21:12.978 D/PermissionCache(  190): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=2000 => granted (547 us)
05-14 15:21:13.121 I/ActivityManager(  510): Process com.maxwell.phone (pid 7548) has died
05-14 15:21:13.121 D/ActivityManager(  510): cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 7548
05-14 15:21:13.122 W/ActivityManager(  510): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.maxwell.phone/.services.SipService in 346942704ms
05-14 15:21:13.122 W/ActivityManager(  510): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.maxwell.phone/.services.InfoWidgetService in 1000ms
05-14 15:21:13.122 W/ActivityManager(  510): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.maxwell.phone/.services.BluetoothPhoneService in 11000ms
05-14 15:21:13.394 I/imx6.gralloc( 9992): open gpu gralloc module!
05-14 15:21:15.502 W/sh      ( 9996): type=1400 audit(0.0:17): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728777]" dev="sockfs" ino=728777 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:15.522 W/sh      ( 9996): type=1400 audit(0.0:18): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728777]" dev="sockfs" ino=728777 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:15.627 E/cutils-trace( 9998): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-14 15:21:15.658 I/imx6.gralloc( 9998): open gpu gralloc module!
05-14 15:21:17.782 W/sh      (10001): type=1400 audit(0.0:19): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728786]" dev="sockfs" ino=728786 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:17.782 W/sh      (10001): type=1400 audit(0.0:20): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728786]" dev="sockfs" ino=728786 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:17.905 E/cutils-trace(10003): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-14 15:21:17.934 I/imx6.gralloc(10003): open gpu gralloc module!
05-14 15:21:19.952 W/sh      (10006): type=1400 audit(0.0:21): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728788]" dev="sockfs" ino=728788 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:19.952 W/sh      (10006): type=1400 audit(0.0:22): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728788]" dev="sockfs" ino=728788 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:20.099 E/cutils-trace(10008): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-14 15:21:20.198 I/imx6.gralloc(10008): open gpu gralloc module!
05-14 15:21:22.262 W/sh      (10011): type=1400 audit(0.0:23): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728797]" dev="sockfs" ino=728797 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:22.272 W/sh      (10011): type=1400 audit(0.0:24): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728797]" dev="sockfs" ino=728797 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:22.396 E/cutils-trace(10013): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-14 15:21:22.427 I/imx6.gralloc(10013): open gpu gralloc module!
05-14 15:21:24.452 W/sh      (10016): type=1400 audit(0.0:25): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728807]" dev="sockfs" ino=728807 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:24.452 W/sh      (10016): type=1400 audit(0.0:26): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728807]" dev="sockfs" ino=728807 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:24.482 W/sh      (10018): type=1400 audit(0.0:27): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728807]" dev="sockfs" ino=728807 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:24.482 W/sh      (10018): type=1400 audit(0.0:28): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[728807]" dev="sockfs" ino=728807 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
05-14 15:21:24.811 D/AndroidRuntime(10018): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
05-14 15:21:24.816 D/AndroidRuntime(10018): CheckJNI is OFF
05-14 15:21:24.863 E/cutils-trace(10018): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-14 15:21:24.928 E/memtrack(10018): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-14 15:21:24.928 E/android.os.Debug(10018): failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-14 15:21:24.996 D/AndroidRuntime(10018): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
05-14 15:21:25.026 I/art     (10018): System.exit called, status: 0
05-14 15:21:25.026 I/AndroidRuntime(10018): VM exiting with result code 0.
```

Comment: Does the device use any custom skin/ROM? If yes, which one?

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, then try to strip feaures one by one, to find out which causes the crash - even with degradation of your application features. If you have a non-crashing version, add features one-by-one, to see which combination of features is crashing - it is possible that not a single feature will cause the issue. Then you can get deeper, more fine-grained. After you have the cause you'll surely know how to deal with it - throw out the feature, write a workaround, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant reproduce it in a proper way. It just happens. Sometimes after days of working fine. Sometimes it happens very fast (after some hours). That makes it very hard to do a binary search.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal: It uses a potentially customized android rom from gigaset. Nothing I can change or dive into.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for but its likely to be a bug in the OS - not Android itself per se but a lot of manufacturers use their own version of Android to make minor tweaks or add additional functionality that's unique to them that isn't part of the standard stock Android.

I had something similar where I'd get a device crash - not quite as severe as locking the entire device - this sounds like a particular buggy version, it was a Sumsung Galaxy S3 I think it was, but unfortunately there's not a lot you can do.

You could try contacting the manufacturer and see if the can shed any light onto the problem but not sure you'd get very far.

Comment: You are right: It is not the answer I was looking for. But I am afraid, you might be right. The manufacturer said, I am the only one with this problem, which made me hope, I might be causing the issue on my side. Because only in this case I could fix it. I still have no idea what could possibly get the OS to crash that hard from a regular app.

Comment: Yea pretty much impossible - its probably not likely to be anything specific to your code if it works on every other device but this specific hardware. The only thing I can think of its easy to replicate is to connect to the device via ADB in Android Studio and run the app so you can profile it and double check there's not a sudden CPU/RAM spike before the OS crashes - normally the OS would handle that fairly well and kill the app before the OS dies but if there's some quirky bug in this specific Android code they are using it might not be handling it but that is a bit of a stab in the dark

Comment: Unfortunately the freezes happen very irregular. That does make it fairly hard to check with a profiler. Usually the devices freeze during the night without anyone around.
Apart from heavy load on cpu, ram, network-stuff or any combination of them I still have no idea what could cause it. I ll build small sample-apps for a stress-test, but I am not very confident to find anything.

Comment: Ah that's interesting it seems to do it when the device isn't used. Does the device support the doze feature. I've not heard of this happening before but just wondering if the app is trying to do something but Doze is stopping it and the app is going a little screwy because of it. You could try whitelisting the app from doze so it doesn't do battery optimisation on it and see if it resolves the issue. More info on doze can be found at https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: I am afraid doze is not the issue. The app holds a wakelock and keeps the display on. And the device freezes during use, too. It feels totally unpredictable and user input does not seem to influence it in any way. Additional argument: the device in question runs android 5.1 ;-)

Comment: Ah OK, the doze idea was a bit of a guess, running out of ideas you can try unfortunately :(